# kivy property not updating

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

So I'm working on a GUI based on kivy.

And I was quiet irritated by the fact that a togglebutton works with state ("down" and "normal") instead of a boolean so I created my own toggle:

```
class Toggle(ToggleButton):
    pressed = BooleanProperty(False)

    def on_state(self, _, state):
        self.pressed = state == "down"

    def on_pressed(self, _, pressed):
        self.state = "down" if pressed else "normal"
```

In my kv file i have a test button:

```
Main:
    Toggle:
        size_hint: None, 1
        width: 60
        pressed: root.test0
        on_release: root.test()
    Toggle:
        size_hint: None, 1
        width: 60
        pressed: root.test1
        on_release: root.test()
```

With this python code:

```
class Main(BoxLayout):
    test0 = BooleanProperty(False)
    test1 = BooleanProperty(False)

    def test(self):
        print("test", self.test0, self.test1)
```

if I change the value of test0 then switches the buttons state
but if i click on the button test0 doesn't update.

This needs also to work for any other variable like test1.
With kivy Spinner if you add a property to "text" it will automatically update the property.

What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what I tried to do doesn't exist I think. What I said about the spinner automatically updating the property is not true.

I took a sneak peek on the kivy checkbox widget and used that to update my code:

Toggle:

```
class Toggle(ToggleButton):
    def get_active(self):
        return self.state == "down"

    def set_active(self, value):
        self.state = "down" if value else "normal"

    active = AliasProperty(get_active, set_active, bind=("state",))
```

and kv

```
Toggle:
    size_hint: None, 1
    width: 60
    active: root.test0
    on_active: root.test0 = self.active
    on_active: root.test()
```

Now if active changes, test0 will change with it its just a little more work.

Answer (score 0):

This is because `test0` is not set based on the state of the button. Please change the function `on_pressed` like below and it should work as expected:

```
    def on_pressed(self, _, pressed):
        if pressed:
            self.state = "down"
            self.parent.test0 = True
        else:
            self.state = "normal"
            self.parent.test0 = False
```

Comment: This is not quiet what I'm asking, I edited the question.